# H3 Tag and floted DIV collapsing

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that my **H3 Title** and **Floated DIV** (image) are collapsing if I make Border-bottom or Background color to H3 Title; and I am not able to separate them;

I have tried a 2nd version - if I put **Display:Flex** on H3 Title - then a new problem - Title moves too far left;

Display: Block version:

```css
    .layout {
        max-width:600px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px dashed blue;
        width:auto;
    }
    p, h3  {
        max-width:400px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid violet;
        width: auto;
    }
p {border: none;}
p + p, h3 + p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box {
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
h3 {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    background: yellow;
    display:block;
}
.image {
    background: violet;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">


<div class="box">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<h3>Article Title Header</h3>
<p>Rome (Italian and Latin: Roma [ˈroːma] (About this soundlisten)) is the capital city and a special comune of Italy (named Comune di Roma Capitale), </p>

<p>With 2,860,009 residents in 1,285 km2 (496.1 sq mi),[1] it is also the country's most populated comune. It is the third most populous city in the European Union by population within city limits. It is the centre of the Metropolitan City of Rome, which has a population of 4,355,725 residents, thus making it the most populous metropolitan city in Italy.</p>




</div>
```

Display: FLEX version below:

```css
    .layout {
        max-width:600px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px dashed blue;
        width:auto;
    }
    p, h3  {
        max-width:400px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid violet;
        width: auto;
    }
p {border: none;}
p + p, h3 + p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box {
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
h3 {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    background: yellow;
    display:flex;
}
.image {
    background: violet;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">


<div class="box">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<h3>Article Title Header</h3>
<p>Rome (Italian and Latin: Roma [ˈroːma] (About this soundlisten)) is the capital city and a special comune of Italy (named Comune di Roma Capitale), </p>

<p>With 2,860,009 residents in 1,285 km2 (496.1 sq mi),[1] it is also the country's most populated comune. It is the third most populous city in the European Union by population within city limits. It is the centre of the Metropolitan City of Rome, which has a population of 4,355,725 residents, thus making it the most populous metropolitan city in Italy.</p>




</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They overlap with each other because there is a `float: left` for `.box` but there aren't any `float` property for `h3` or `p`

there are several ways to fix it!

you can act like a responsive design and make 2 column for them (which i suggest this solution), you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp).

Or you can add your header and paragraphs into another div as a container for left side and declare a `float: left` for it (you can use both `left` or `right` for `.box` according to your work):

```css
.layout {
        max-width:600px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px dashed blue;
        width:auto;
    }
    p, h3  {
        max-width:400px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid violet;
        width: auto;
    }
p {border: none;}
p + p, h3 + p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box {
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
h3 {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    background: yellow;
    display:block;
}
.image {
    background: violet;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
}
.left-side {
    float: left; /* or float: right; */
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <h3>Article Title Header</h3>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-side">       
        <p>Rome (Italian and Latin: Roma [ˈroːma] (About this soundlisten)) is the capital city and a special comune of Italy (named Comune di Roma Capitale), </p>

        <p>With 2,860,009 residents in 1,285 km2 (496.1 sq mi),[1] it is also the country's most populated comune. It is the third most populous city in the European Union by population within city limits. It is the centre of the Metropolitan City of Rome, which has a population of 4,355,725 residents, thus making it the most populous metropolitan city in Italy.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I corrected the question to remove the `<style>` tags from the stack snippet CSS. You may wish to do the same with your answer snippet.

Comment: @Alohci I just copied question snippet for answer and didn't realized that! , thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: With float you can do probably, if you put all Paragraph in; when I float only H3 tag, and article is much longer, I get 2 floats and article in between, and it doesn't look like a Header anymore;

Comment: you want for header to be at the top of them both? no problem , I edited the snippet, take a look! only thing i've changed was the location of `h3` from previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
.layout {
  max-width:600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  width:auto;
}
    
p + p, 
h3 + p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box {
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 20px
}

h3 {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
  display:block;
}

.image {
    background: violet;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <h3>Article Title Header</h3>
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Rome (Italian and Latin: Roma [ˈroːma] (About this soundlisten)) is the capital city and a special comune of Italy (named Comune di Roma Capitale), </p>
  <p>With 2,860,009 residents in 1,285 km2 (496.1 sq mi),[1] it is also the country's most populated comune. It is the third most populous city in the European Union by population within city limits. It is the centre of the Metropolitan City of Rome, which has a population of 4,355,725 residents, thus making it the most populous metropolitan city in Italy.</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATES:** CSS Grid Solution, Here I wrapped `p` with `DIV`.

```css
.layout {
  max-width:600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 150px; 
  grid-template-rows: auto; 
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "para box";
  gap: 20px;
}
    
h3 {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: title; 
  margin: 0
}

.para {
  grid-area: para; 
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

p + p {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.box {
  grid-area: box;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}


.image {
    background: violet;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <h3>Article Title Header</h3>
  <div class="para">
    <p>Rome (Italian and Latin: Roma [ˈroːma] (About this soundlisten)) is the capital city and a special comune of Italy (named Comune di Roma Capitale), </p>
    <p>With 2,860,009 residents in 1,285 km2 (496.1 sq mi),[1] it is also the country's most populated comune. It is the third most populous city in the European Union by population within city limits. It is the centre of the Metropolitan City of Rome, which has a population of 4,355,725 residents, thus making it the most populous metropolitan city in Italy.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have changed places of Title / Image; that would be good, but for my situation - hard to implement; I am using Drupal Fielded layout - and I either get 1 field - Image, 2-field - Body; or vice versa, but it's almost impossible H3 tag from Body field to change places with another field - Image;

Answer (score 0):

**Why you don't use CSS flex property**

Why u don't give at try of CSS flex property to achieve your goal? Flex is safe and fun for such complexity. Here I implement flex version of your problem solution.

```css
 .layout {
      max-width:600px;
      margin: auto;
      border: 1px dashed blue;
      width:auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  p, h3  {
      max-width:400px;
      margin: auto;
      border: 1px solid violet;
      width: auto;
  }
  p {border: none;}
  p + p, h3 + p {
      margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .box {
      width:150px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 2px solid green;
  }
  h3 {
      color: red;
      border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
      background: yellow;
      display:flex;
  }
  .image {
      background: violet;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 80%;
      height: 80%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="box">
      <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h3>Article Title Header</h3>
      <p>Rome (Italian and Latin: Roma [ˈroːma] (About this soundlisten)) is the capital city and a special comune of Italy (named Comune di Roma Capitale), 
      </p>

        <p>
        With 2,860,009 residents in 1,285 km2 (496.1 sq mi),[1] it is also the country's most populated comune. It is the third most populous city in the European Union by population within city limits. It is the centre of the Metropolitan City of Rome, which has a population of 4,355,725 residents, thus making it the most populous metropolitan city in Italy.
        </p>
   </div>
</div>
```